# asp.net numeric "TextBox" with both comma and dot

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have an asp.net `TextBox` with numeric `TextMode` which accepts just numbers and dot.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
```

How can I change/subclass it so that it also accepts comma?

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried.

Comment: Numeric textbox just accept number and dot. there is no code for that. I just need to have comma also.

Answer (score 0):

Using `TextMode="Number"` allows the browser to enforce the application of numbers only.  I'm not aware you can change this reliably on all browsers.  It might be better to remove the textmode and add some JavaScript to detect key press and check if the key is 0-9 dot or comma.